# Use python math library in degree mode

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I need calculate the tangent of a triangle using the `math.tan` function  however the python math library calculates in radius mode, I need it to calculate in degree mode.

everyone seems to be saying that I need to take the product of `math.tan` which is in radius and convert it to degree with the following equation (`(180 / math.pi) * (math.tan(num)`) however this will not work in a calculation as if you where to put the equation "tan(15)" into a calculator in degree mode it will return 0.26794919243 but if you calculate tan(15) in radius mode **and then** convert it using the conversion equation you get  -49.04480916310798

Two very different answers making the answer useless to me.

But that is not all I tried, math library also has a degree convert function (`math.degree`), which unsurprisingly just gives me the same answer (-49.04480916310798).

I just need a way to calculate in degree mode with python that will return a degree answer from tan(x) as if it where done on a calculator in degree mode.

Comment: To take the tan of 15 degrees, you want `tan(radians(15))`, or `tan(15 / 180 * pi)`, if you want to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes both those methods worked. thanks allot.